# Image next to registration

Tags: html, css

I have this registration with HTML:

```
<form class="registerForm" id="registerForm" action="./index_public.php?page=pilot_insert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Name</span>
            </td>
            <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
                          <label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" />
                          </label>
                          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*Required</span></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style1">E-mail</td>
            <td><span id="sprytextfield6">
                        <label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="8"/>
                        </label>
                        <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">*Required</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Formato no válido.</span></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input class="btn" value=Apply name=apply type="submit" />
</form>
```

I want put an image next to the registration form. I tryed but I only can put it below the registration form and no next to. HELP!!!

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put form and image in div and use "float" css property.

```
 <div style="float:right">
<img src="http://assetprotectionsecured.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/alert_png.png">     </div>
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7uUK8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Apply a specific width to your form and `float:left` and use `float:right` for the image

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying "display:inline-block;" to both the form and the image.

For example:

```
<form style="display:inline-block;"></form>
<img src="someimage" style="display:inline-block;"/>
```

Here's a fiddle example with your form and an image side by side: http://jsfiddle.net/VE66w/

Answer (score 0):

Use `div` or `span` to make two container in `body` of the html one is use for form and other is use image. After that apply css according.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete : "Formato no válido."

```
  <div style="float:right"><img src="http://assetprotectionsecured.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/alert_png.png"></div>
```

If you want, image next to registration field ...